# Apending some special character in file

Tags: command-line, files

I have one file. I want to add `'` at evry line beginning.also after first word complete I want to put `'` again and then `,` after that I want repeat the same first word in `'same word'`. How can I do this ?

e.g.

```
abc
xyz
pqr
mno
```

will be converted into

```
'abc','abc'
'xyz','xyz'
'pqr','pqr'
'mno','mno'
```

I have thousands of such lines.How can I achieve this ? I am using ubuntu 16.04.

I am getting output as shown below .

[image]

What I want is :

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Why do you write "first word"? Your lines contain only one word each. If you actual file has more than one word, please update your question to reflext the actual file format.

Comment: @Philippos  yes, I have only one word in each line. but I want same word with ' ' , after that word. That's why I have added word "first" , next can be second with same pattern.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. This makes it impossible to work with actual data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed "s/.*/'&','&'/" filename
```

`s/foo/bar` replaces `foo` by `bar`. `.*` matches the whole line, `&` in the replacement section inserts the whole match.

Comment: doing nothing ! My file is not going to take any single change. What to do ?

Comment: You mean, the output of the command is just the file listed? Hard to believe. Or do you want to modify the file directly? In this case add option `-i` to your GNU `sed` to edit the file in place.

Comment: -i works like magic. Thank @philippos.

Comment: also can u please suggest how to avoid new line ? I want both the word with special character in same line.

Comment: WHich new line? I don't get any new lines.

Comment: I am getting this as output:

'LIPSA
','LIPSA'

in three different line.
'

Comment: Please edit your question to have some file example to reproduce that effect.

Comment: I have edited question for more clear idea of what I exactly want.

Comment: Looks like there is some invisible extra character at the end of each line, like a carriage return. Please post the output of `sed -n "l;5q" filename` to make the mystery visible.

Answer (score 2):

You have already got a `sed` answer. Here are a few alternatives:

---

`awk`: Setting single quote as variable `q` (for readability) and `out` as the record surrounded by single quotes, then printing `out` with desired formatting:

```
awk -v q="'" '{out=q$0q; print out","out}'
```

---

`bash`: Reading each line, setting up variable `out` to contain the line surrounded by single quotes, and finally printing in desired format:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do out="'$line'"; printf '%s,%s\n' "$out" "$out"; done
```

---

`python`: Reading each line, and printing in desired format using `print()` function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
            print("'{}','{}'".format(line, line))
```

---

`perl`: Replacing each line (`.*`) with proper formatting, `$&` in the replacement stands for the matched portion, in this case the whole line:

```
perl -pe "s/.*/'$&','$&'/"
```

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
abc
xyz
pqr
mno

% awk -v q="'" '{out=q$0q; print out","out}' file.txt
'abc','abc'
'xyz','xyz'
'pqr','pqr'
'mno','mno'

% while IFS= read -r line; do out="'$line'"; printf '%s,%s\n' "$out" "$out"; done <file.txt
'abc','abc'
'xyz','xyz'
'pqr','pqr'
'mno','mno'

% perl -pe "s/.*/'$&','$&'/" file.txt
'abc','abc'
'xyz','xyz'
'pqr','pqr'
'mno','mno'
```